# Navigate into page waiting data from the previous with angular and typescript

Tags: typescript, angular6

First i add a metier, and on submitting my form i need to navigate into another page with the id of metier, 
but cause of async function the id is not yet available 
can you help me please ?

metier.services.ts

```
addMetier(metierObject: Metier) {
    this.httpClient
        .post<any>('http://localhost:8080/metiers', metierObject)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('data', data);
                this.idMetier = data['id'];
                console.log('POST Request is successfulllll ', this.idMetier);
            },
            error => {
                console.log('Error', error);
            }
        );
}
```

add.compenent.ts

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.metierObject = new Metier(
        this.form.value['name'],
        this.form.value['mission'],
        this.form.value['activites'],
        this.form.value['competences']
    );

    this.metierService.addMetier(this.metierObject);
    this.router.navigate([`/metiers/addMetier/${this.metierService.idMetier}/competences`]);
}
```

Comment: Try:`if(data){// your code}`

Comment: Thanks @PrashantPimpale but the answer of Nguyen resolved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make the addMetier from the service return an Observable

```
addMetier(metierObject: Metier) {
    return new Observable((subscriber) => {
        this.httpClient
            .post<any>('http://localhost:8080/metiers', metierObject)
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log('data', data);
                    this.idMetier = data['id'];
                    console.log('POST Request is successfulllll ', this.idMetier);
                    subscriber.next(data['id']);
                },
                error => {
                    console.log('Error', error);
                    subscriber.error(data['id']);
                }
            );
    });
}
```

Second you can subscribe the change and navigate after that

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.metierObject = new Metier(
        this.form.value['name'],
        this.form.value['mission'],
        this.form.value['activites'],
        this.form.value['competences']
    );


    this.metierService.addMetier(this.metierObject).subscribe((id) => {
        this.router.navigate([`/metiers/addMetier/${id}/competences`]);
    });
}
```

And don't forget ti import the Observable

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Hope this help